# Alteryx MongoDB Output Performance

Tags: mongodb, alteryx

I'm trying to write on my mongo collection about 1 million rows, but it's taking too much time (actually it never ends).

Looking at mongo log I can see that the insert queries are called every time, there is no bulk operation.

Does Alteryx support bulk insert for Mongo?

I'm using Alteryx 10.1 and MongoDB 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer at this moment is no, Alteryx doesn't support bulk insert for Mongo.